# Any ideas as to why this jQuery does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have an HTML page where a `click` event is captured and hides `#testContent`. I put the HTML and Javascript in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/VSXY7/1/ . For some reason in the actual page the `.click()` does not work, but in the jsFiddle works. Does anybody have a clue why this would be?

I have ensured that the jQuery and Javascript file were both correctly attached and show up in the Webkit Inspect and Firebug. I am not getting console errors either. It's quite confusing.

UPDATE:
You can check out the actual page here: http://blankit.co.cc/test/77/

Comment: Do you see any errors in firebug?

Comment: @locrizak nope, no errors at all.

Comment: Is the click within a document.ready or are you loading the div dynamically?

Comment: @locrizak its loaded when the page loads.

Comment: Check if the event handler was added to the element in [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/elements.html) or Firebug.

Comment: @Anurag How would you check for that?

Comment: see the Chrome link I attached - http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/elements.html. Scroll down to the section that says "Event Listeners". Firefox also has something similar I believe, native or through an extension.

Comment: @Anurag ok, thanks. it says there are no event listeners. The thing that is strange is that all the javascript I add to the file does not work. I tried alerts, console.logs etc. so strange.

Comment: is your actual code online somewhere for us to look at?

Comment: @Anurag Here is the page that dynamically generates the page from the database: http://pastebin.com/eS4gLRCh . more coming

Comment: and here is the header: http://pastebin.com/RQRACvFx - all PHP

Comment: The strange thing is that the navbar.js is working fine so that means jquery.js is working fine too.

Comment: this'd be a lot easier to look at if we could see what was happening with te real site - the fiddle doesn't let us see your directory structure and HTTP statuses etc

Comment: @tobyodavies thats true, you can check it out here: http://blankit.co.cc/test/77/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script tag has a typo in the type change it to `text/javascript` you are missing a letter.

Change study.js from

```
$(function(){

console.log('hello');
alert('hello');
/*var testContent = $('#testContent').val();
var contentArray = testContent.split(" ");

$('#studyTestLink').click(function() {

     $('#testContent').hide();
     alert('hello');


});*/

});
```

to

```
$(function(){

$('#studyTestLink').click(function() {


   var testContent = $('#testContent').val();
    var contentArray = testContent.split(" ");

     $('#testContent').hide();
     alert('hello');


});

});
```

Comment: I tried an absolute url and it made no difference. jquery.js and navbar.js are clearly both working.

Comment: @chromedude - Not absolute, just take out the `../../` so it looks like the one that is working.

Comment: without seeing the actual page you can't have any idea that relative URLs have anything to do with the problem...

Comment: @tobyodavies -- he said in his comments it is strange that navbar works and jQuery does not.  Look at the code I copied above from his pastebin -- what is the difference between the thing that works and the one that does not?  If he JUST WOULD MAKE THAT CHANGE then it would work.

Comment: @Hogan I am not sure where you got that navbar.js does not have `../../`, but as far as I can see it does.

Comment: @Hogan I see what you are talking about, but you are taking to different parts of that if statement. This page only applies to the `else if` clause.

Comment: @Hogan if you go to http://blankit.co.cc/test/77/ you will see that all the files are loaded correctly.

Comment: @chromedude -- exactly -- Take it out!

Comment: @Chromedude - in that example you have the code you are trying to get work commented out... that is why it does not work.

Comment: @Hogan Im taking out the comment now... but originally that was not there. I commented it out to see if the alert would work (as you saw it didn't)

Comment: I still see the comments and the alert came up for me.

Comment: @Hogan sorry it took me a little longer to get it and I think the alert was from navbar.js where I had one. I just removed that one too.

Comment: I'm still looking -- strange... give me a min.

Comment: @Hogan just tried putting the file in the `test` directory -- showed the exact same thing

Comment: @Hogan just did, No difference.

Comment: It is not different fix the typo in `type="text/javasript"` it is missing a `c`

Comment: @Hogan did that - no dif are you getting a difference?

Comment: @Hogan got it! thanks so much! now I will be banging my head against a wall for the next couple days thinking about how I spent 2 hours trying to find a missing `c` thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your javascript is not loaded correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../includes/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../../includes/navbar.js"></script><script type="text/javasript" src="../../includes/study.js"></script>
```

You can put some **alert()** function inside your javascript file to make sure it is loaded correctly.

Comment: hmm... what do you mean? `../../includes/study.js` is the script that I am having problems with.

Comment: it could be, you can put a alert() to make sure whether the javascript is loaded correctly or not.

Comment: @jumperchen I put an alert() and it doesn't work. Its so strange though because in firebug and chrome it shows that its attached.

Comment: The strange thing is that the navbar.js is working great therfore jquery.js is working fine and study.js is at the same level as both those scripts in my server.

Comment: you can try to put the three javascript files and the html file in the same folder, and try them again. If the alert() function is not working, it means your javascript is not loaded correctly. Or is there a wrong idiom in your javascript file? like miss a comma or add more extra comma to stop the Javascript running.

Comment: @jumperchen I copied and pasted the code directly into jsFiddle... and it works great there. Also I haved checked it multiple times for errors. Not seeing anything at all. An alert in navbar.js works great.

Answer (score 1):

I added your code to a page (using jquery 1.5.2) and it works fine. Don't you have any other code that could be breaking it?

Comment: yeah, here is the php that dynamically generates the page: pastebin.com/eS4gLRCh and heres the header: pastebin.com/RQRACvFx .

Comment: I mean, some other javascript code could be breaking it. I don't know what is inside navbar.js or study.js and if they are being called.

Comment: study.js is the code that is not working. navbar.js is here: http://pastebin.com/AjK2E2wK . and just updated the jsFiddle with the added navbar.js code and it still works great (http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/VSXY7/4/)